# R markdown knitting errors with repeated chunks

Tags: r, r-markdown

I included a check to install an R package if it's not already installed by the following syntax:

````
```{r setup-packages, results=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
if(! require("readxl")) install.packages("readxl")
```
````

which returns this error:

```
processing file: Testing.Rmd
Error in parse_block(g[-1], g[1], params.src, markdown_mode) : 

  Duplicate chunk label 'setup-packages', which has been used for the chunk:

if(! require("readxl")) install.packages("readxl")

Calls: <Anonymous> ... process_file -> split_file -> lapply -> FUN -> parse_block

Execution halted
```

The knitting works if I change `{r setup-packages, results=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}` to `{r}`.

I want to reuse this chunk `{r setup-packages, results=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}` for each package but it only works once.  Can someone explain or provide a solution to make it work with other packages?

Comment: This error is telling you that you have chunks with the same name. They each must have unique names or no name at all. Even if they don't have a name, they can still have chunk options, though.

Comment: Thanks @Kat. I renamed it to setup-packages1 or anything different to setup-packages and it works.

Answer (score 0):

knitr is erroring due to the reuse of a chunk name.  Each chunk must be unnamed, as you found works with just `{r}`, or uniquely named.

You can fix it in any of these ways:

1. Put the lines for each of your package checks in a single chunk.
2. Rename each chunk to have a unique name, like `setup-packages-readxl`.
3. Set the option `options(knitr.duplicate.label = "allow")` in your Rprofile, though this is not a recommended use of this power according to the [knitr documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/duplicate-label.html).